# How to display near by events and venues on google map based on user current location

Tags: android, google-maps, foursquare

Here i am able to display User on google map by getting user latitude and longitude now i want to display near by events happening in user location and want to display nearby venues so chosen foursquare api.[here it is](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search) 
[2nd one](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events)
Here is my code to display user on map

```
        R.id.map)).getMap();
    // Creating location manager and location classes instances
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);
    ;
    mCurrentLocation = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    // if location found display as a toast the current latitude and
    // longitude
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Current location:\nLatitude: "
                        + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "\n"
                        + "Longitude: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        USER_LOCATION = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(USER_LOCATION).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)).title("Your current location"));
         // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(USER_LOCATION, 12));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

give me a brief idea how to use that api.based on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but do you want a complete tutorial for copy&paste?

You managed to get a location, you have a documentation of the api you want to use... so use it?

Take the location you have from Android. Format it so that the api can use it (perhaps they need coordinates, perhaps a city name, ...) and then call the web service. You will get a result and have to interpret it.

Where is actually your problem?

Comment: i don't want complete tutorial to copy & paste.In fouresquare api they are using Geo points(related to google maps v1),i am using mapsv2 ,felt difficult to use that ,so posted here for suggestions..if know any alternative Api that displays events  happening nearby to user and which implementation based on google maps v2 tell me .that's enough for me

Comment: Okay, with `mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()` you already have latitude and longitude of userposition and according to the documentation of foursquare: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore you can provide these two values to get a list of venues or you could provide a geocodable city. But you already have (almost) exact coordinates, so use them.

So read the docs (Google Maps & FourSquare) and go! This was a 2 minute search ... ;)

Comment: I will get events from different sites and will show the user after taking their locations.